# Redirect requests to my external IP/port to a different external IP/port?

Tags: iptables, redirect

Is it possible to redirect connections to a specific IP/port to an external IP/port?

Example:

- Server A has the external IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
- Server B has the external IP yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
- User sends a request to server A on port 2106, I want to redirect it to server B at port 2106.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Is machine "A" a multihomed gateway? If yes, iptables could probably be used. Example: iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 2106 -j DNAT --to y.y.y.y:2106
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 2106 -i eth1 -j ACCEPT

Comment: @bumbling fool thanks I had already solved it and posted below what I did.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport port -j DNAT --to-destination ip:port
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Where ip and port are the target server I want to redirect the current server port to.

Comment: This does not work for me.  Specifically, that last line causes all traffic from my machine to itself to appear to come from outside, and similar problems.

Comment: @Prix wouldn't that redirect all traffic to a specified port (2106) to yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:port? What if I'd like to redirect traffic that goes only to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port?