# iptables port forwarding

Tags: iptables

I want to forward the traffic from 85.25.47.11:9999 (linux) to 62.75.130.241:9987
You can see the IP is different.
Is it possible to forward it in this way

Comment: Please see this answer: [Redirect requests to my external IP/port to a different external IP/port?](http://askubuntu.com/q/28516/206413)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/rinetd-redirects-tcp-connections-from-one-ip-address-and-port-to-another.html illustrates how to forward from address A, port X to address B, port Y, following rules defined in /etc.rinetd.conf e.g.,

```
# bindadress bindport connectaddress connectport

192.168.2.1 80 192.168.2.3 180

192.168.2.1 443 192.168.2.3 443
```

with details at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/rinetd.8.html