# Redirect requests to my external IP/port to a internal IP/port?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have a dedicated server running KVM virtualization with n public IP addresses dedicated to n-1 web-facing virtual machines. Now I'd like to set up some web-facing VM's that don't have a dedicated address, but instead will have 2 or 3 ports forwarded for them from the host machine.

Bridge configuration is:

```
brctl show
```

[image]

Let's say I would like to forward

- 178.126.193.153:201 to 192.168.1.101:22
- 178.126.193.153:801 to 192.168.1.101:80

First, I have enabled port forwarding on a host machine by uncommenting
    # net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, then I did
    sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
    service network restart
Then, similar to the recipe in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/28516/181242), I did:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i br0 --dport 201 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101:22
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.101 --dport 201 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i br0 --dport 801 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.101 --dport 801 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

I ran `ifconfig` on a guest machine and checked that its interface eth0, indeed, has the IP address 192.168.1.101. The interface inside of virtual machine is called `eth0`, is this right?

But it doesn't work:

`nmap 178.126.193.153` doesn't show an open port 201 nor 801, and `ssh -l root -p 201 178.126.193.153` gets me

```
ssh: connect to host 178.162.193.153 port 201: Connection refused
```

`ip route` on a host machine returns
    178.126.193.128/26 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 178.162.193.153 
    192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 
    169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  scope link  metric 1004 
    default via 178.126.193.190 dev br0

What am I doing wrong?